# textView's text changes, when I set the background to clear color

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview

I am using a invisible `textView` with its **background color** to `clearColor`. The view container of this textView has **generericGray** color. I also set the `textView` text color to **white**, but when I check out running my program the text color is **black**! Has this thing happened to anyone?

Comment: Used Storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: @raurora I did set it in Interface Builder (storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

When you click on `Text View` in the document outline. The font color is white.

If you scroll down to the view, the background is Clear Color (Text View will have grayscale and alpha values are both 0.0). Play with the 'Alpha' value to see the difference. I have set gray as the background of my view, so that the text is visible.  Hope, this helps.

[image]

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the containing view has a generic gray color. That what I think its causing this issue.

Comment: No I did not, I did add the color of the textView the same that you did, but the issue I think is with genericGray color. I have never used generic colors